# $27 | (2x+1)^2 \implies 2x$ is a multiple of 9?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Found this simple fact in a proof that I was looking up, and am confused as to why it is true:

Why does $27 | (2x+1)^2 \implies 2x + 1$ is a multiple of 9?

Comment: That is certainly wrong, because $x=4$ gives $28\mid (2x+1)^2$, but $2x$ is not a multiple of 9. There is an error somewhere.

Comment: Do you mean $2x+1$ is a multiple of $9$?

Comment: @MJD - Why not post this as an answer ?

Comment: @belgi Because I don't feel like I understand what is really going on here.  If OP had provided a source, I would post an answer that says definitively “there is a misprint” or “you misunderstood”.  But as it is I don't feel that I have the true answer.  You should feel free to repost my comment as an answer if you like.  (Added: having seen that N.S. and graydad have posted much more pertinent replies, I am glad I did not post my observation as an answer.)

Comment: My apologies -- I meant $2x + 1$

Comment: @RyanYu Then edit the title of your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably mean that $2x+1$ is a multiple of $9$.

First since $27 | (2x+1)^2 $ we have $3|(2x+1)(2x+1)$. As $3$ is prime we get that $3|2x+1$.

Write $2x+1=3n$. Then 
$$27|9n^2$$ implies $3|n^2$. Again, since $3$ is prime $3|n$. Write $n=3m$ and you get
$$2x+1=9m$$
with $m$ an integer.

**P.S.** An alternative proof is to write the prime factorization 
$$2x+1=p_1^{k_1}....p_n^{k_n}$$
Then 
$$(2x+1)^2=p_1^{2k_1}....p_n^{2k_n}$$

Since this is divisible by $27$ it follows that some $p_i=3$ and its power $2k_i \geq 3$. Since $k_i$ is integer, it follows $k_i \geq 2$.

Thus $3^{k_i}|2x+1$ and $k_i \geq 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you instead mean $2x+1$ is a multiple of $9$ note that $27=3^3$ so $3$ must show up as a factor in $(2x+1)^2$ at least $3$ times.  Also note that any prime factor of $2x+1$ will show up in $(2x+1)^2$ an **even** number of times due to the squaring.  Hence, we need at least two factors of $3$ (i.e.$3^2=9$) to be in the prime factorization of $2x+1$.